# Python Test Loader using Nose

Tags: python, nose

I am a beginner at Python and the Nose framework. What I need to do is to write a Test Loader that will load tests using Nose.The results of the test has to be generated as a HTML report. Can someone give me a description about how to do this. I want to know what are the python test case files to write, what are the libraries to include. Please give me a start on this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read through the Nose docs? What have you done so far?

Comment: Have read through the nose docs.I understand there is a class called TestLoader and we can use options(), configure()_loadTestsFromNames() and starttest(). But I am not sure how to use them. A small example will help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the capability that you describe already exists in Nose.

- Nose discovers and loads tests.
- Nose can print output in a variety of formats, including XML (with a plug-in).

If you install Nose and the [NoseXML](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/NoseXML/) or [NoseXMLUnit](http://nosexunit.sourceforge.net/) plugin, I believe that you should have what you need.  If you truly need HTML instead of XML, use one of those plugins as a base to write your own. (And make sure to add it to the [list of third-party plugins](https://nose-plugins.jottit.com/)).